# Products QTY and Add to Card in Admin

Tags: module, addtocart, quantity, magento-1.9.4.1

I need to create a Custom Module for update fast QTY (increase or decrease) in stock. My customer don't want to open each product and go to inventory and type the current stock and save. For this I made a custom template, but now I cant get this done. [image]

Comment: what issue you are facing ? as for my knowledge you have to pass it by query string from the template while adding products to the cart.

Comment: I want to get this done..Don´t know how to do it.

Comment: You have to first products then set forms for different products with submit to cart like above url.check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37705549/magento-2-how-to-generate-add-to-cart-url